# How can I monitor the process of neutral network training?

Tags: dynamic, machine-learning, neural-networks, internet, real-time

In the Linux command line,type `wolfram` then use `NetTrain[net, mnist, Automatic, "LossEvolutionPlot"]` can get the `LossEvolutionPlot`.But how can we view the `LossEvolutionPlot` in realtime **if don't use frontend**?

In the `tensorflow` there is `tensorboard`,we can monitor the process of training via browser.Can we do things like this in `Mathematica`?

[image]

Comment: If you want to monitor the training while running a kernel in Linux without a frontend, maybe you should consider using Mathematica's remote kernel functionality. You can use the frontend on your local machine and connect to the kernel on the remote machine.

Comment: NetTrain produces a dynamic window output you can follow up with. You can use it either on your desktop or in the cloud (I guess in every Wolfram environment). Did you try, and it didn't work?

Comment: I try.it throws error. ref：https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146823/error-occurred-while-connecting-to-remote-kernel-cant-use-dynamic

Comment: Then you have to wait for that question to be answered.

Comment: For now, you could use TrainingProgressFunction option to save the losses in a log file every few seconds and then dynamically plot that with some other program (a jupyter notebook connected to the remote machine, for example) or periodically sync that file with your local machine.