# Error occurred while connecting to remote kernel.Can't use dynamic

Tags: bugs, remote-access

When Open Mathematica using remote kernel,it throws `LinkConnect` error.But normal command can evaluate.Like `Range@5`,`$Version`...

But Can't use dynamic.It throws `An unknown box name`.

[image]

So if I want to monitor training process of neutral networks,it fails.

[image]

Kernel Configuration options:

[image]

Ps:
*frontend*: windows 10

> 11.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 13, 2017)

*kernel*: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

> 11.1.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 18, 2017)

Comment: But the FrontEnd in your screenshot is Linux. But anyway what you want to do might be at best hard to achieve.

Comment: @RolfMertig all screenshot are in windows.The FrontEnd in windows is using Linux's mma as kernel now,so type `$version` it print `11.1.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 18, 2017)`

Comment: V11.1 changed the way kernels connect to the front end, which broke all known method of remote connection

Comment: @M.R. I haven't tested it, but even the method in the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ConnectToARemoteKernel.html) is broken now? If that's true we should consider it as a bug.

Comment: Have the exact same problem. This also causes random crashes for me, making it impossible to use remote kernels longer than a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bug fixed in Version *11.2***

***Now,Dynamic content display correctly!***

[image]

Comment: Hi partida, are you using AWS? if so have you figured out how to use a pem key in the kernel config options?

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that this doesn't work still in 11.2 [image]

Comment: Not even in 12.1