# Remote kernels, Neural Networks and formatting of Dynamic content

Tags: bugs, dynamic, mathlink-or-wstp, neural-networks, remote-access

**Bug fixed in 11.2**

---

I have a few GPU/CPU 'loaded' Linux boxes in my lab, used largely for rendering. I want to compare the new 11.1 Neural Network stuff to some Tensorflow things we do here. Of course, since I have all that iron back there I want to use it.

I don't want to have to actually *walk* all that way, and besides, they are headless (or head-impaired).

I haven't tried using remote kernels for anything other than `Parallel` stuff in quite a while (like, 1990 or so, with a Cray). I've noticed that the 'Basic' settings in `Evaluation->Kernel Configuration Options ...` don't work so I had to go and manually get a connection to happen, thanks to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76459/how-to-connect-the-front-end-of-one-raspberry-pi-with-the-kernel-of-another/76687) I was able to cobble something together that works.

Except -

Things that contain `Dynamic` content aren't happy. To wit, here's an example, first evaluated on the Local machine, then evaluated on the remote -

[image: painful memories]

The resulting `NetChain` isn't formatted when returning from the remote kernel. The error -

```
A GridBox with an invalid first argument was encountered. The first argument to GridBox must be a rectangular matrix (nested list).
```

makes a little bit of sense, spelunking the thing returned -

```
DynamicBox[GridBox[{{
        NeuralNetworks`Private`NetChain`MouseClickBoxes[...
```

suggests to me that there are things that don't get faithfully interpreted by the front-end's kernel when they come back from the remote.

This wouldn't be a problem, other than I would like to run the learning remotely and observe the progress on the front end. This is further reinforced to me by the fact that, if I cut-and-paste the 'red-box' output from the remote-kernel'd notebook into a local-kernel notebook, it renders properly.

Any thoughts on how to get the local notebook kernel to jibe with the output of the remote kernel?

**Edit:** Fixed in 11.2

Comment: This is broken since 11.1.

Comment: Yes,I have the same problem as you.ref:https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146823/error-occurred-while-connecting-to-remote-kernel-cant-use-dynamic

Comment: Same problem here. Plus random crashes.

Comment: According to WRI, known bug. They're working on it™ In the mean time `Developer\`$DisableInteractivity = True` makes the graphs show up w/o interactivity, of course.

Comment: Any change that this has been fixed in 11.2? As the bug from @partida : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146823/error-occurred-while-connecting-to-remote-kernel-cant-use-dynamic

Comment: @flip It has been fixed in 11.2

Comment: @partida, now I can't connect at all

Comment: @partida May I ask what method/solution you are using to connect to your remote kernel?

Comment: You can refer my post https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146823/error-occurred-while-connecting-to-remote-kernel-cant-use-dynamic.There is a image about configuration